# Issue with error catching in Meteor

Tags: meteor, error-handling, try-catch, box

I am calling an external API (Box) using the HTTP methods in Meteor. These work fine, but I am trying to implement some error handling and am running into issues with catching the errors.

```
Meteor.methods({
    copyTemplateFolder: function () {
    this.unblock();
    var accessToken = Meteor.user().services.box.accessToken;

    var apiURL = "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID/copy";
    var apiCall = HTTP.post(apiURL, {
      params: {access_token: accessToken},
      data: {
        "parent": {
          "id" : FOLDER_ID
        },
        "name": "New Folder"
      }
    });

    try {

      var response = apiCall;
      console.log(response.data);

      return response.data;
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
});
```

I've replaced some IDs, etc but the code works fine when there is not an error. But when there is an error the code within `catch` never fires. Everything I've read says this is how it should be done.

Anyone see any issues with what I'm doing?

Comment: is there a typo or are you indeed not calling apiCall? (`apiCall` instead of 'apiCall()')

Comment: I'm not calling it. It works as is and if I use `apiCall()` instead I get an "Object is not a function" error. But the interesting thing is that `catch` worked for that error. So it seems like it's just not catching API response errors?

Comment: never mind, I misread the code; the variable name is a little misleading. it's not the call, it's the response from the call.

Comment: Good point, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your try-block doesn't contain the part where the actual exception occurs. The exception will be thrown by the `post` call. Retrieving a sub-field from an existing variable never causes an exception, even if that field is undefined.

This might be what you want:

```
Meteor.methods({
    copyTemplateFolder: function () {
    this.unblock();
    var accessToken = Meteor.user().services.box.accessToken;

    var apiURL = "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID/copy";
    try {
      var response = HTTP.post(apiURL, {
        params: {access_token: accessToken},
        data: {
          "parent": {
            "id" : FOLDER_ID
          },
          "name": "New Folder"
        }
      });

      console.log(response.data);
      return response.data;

    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
});
```